# How to store image using ActiveAndroid in DB

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, activeandroid

This My My Activity class code for Storing Values using activeandoid ...    i have converted image file to byte in below code .. but it is not Stored in Db ...All other values were stored

```
case R.id.notVerified:
                    ActiveAndroid.beginTransaction();
                    try {
                        c.setName(Ename.getText().toString());
                        c.setEmail(Eemail.getText().toString());
                        c.setMemo(Eemail.getText().toString());
                        c.setPhone(Ephone.getText().toString());
                        c.setPhoto("user.png");
                        String s = new String(byteArray);

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), c.getImage().toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        c.setImage(byteArray);
                        c.setTitle(ETitle.getText().toString());
                        c.save();
                        ActiveAndroid.setTransactionSuccessful();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contact Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } finally {
                        ActiveAndroid.endTransaction();
                    }

                    break;
```

This is for Converting Image to Byte

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Eimgname.setText(filePath);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            c.setImage(byteArray);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActiveAndroid` also provides custom SQL `queries` using `SQLiteUtils class`. There are two methods executing SQL namely, “execSql” and “rawQuery”. The first one is provided for no results `queries`, whereas the second one for `queries` which return the result. In the Listing no. 12 you can find examples of uses of those `methods`.

```
SQLiteUtils.execSql("DELETE FROM Prelegents where id = ?", new String[]{"1"});

List prelegents =
    SQLiteUtils.rawQuery(PrelegentDAO.class, "SELECT * from Prelegents where id = ?", new String[]{"1"});
```

[SEE THIS LINK](http://www.future-processing.pl/blog/persist-your-data-activeandroid-and-parse/)

Answer (score 0):

From performance view, its more useful create a column as a string and get the image from the disk or the web. and AA supports saving byte arrays maybe there is something wrong in your entity class.
and do not forget that defining custom [type serializer](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Type-serializers) could help you.